# Code keeps thowing a NPE, cannot find the cause

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, nullpointerexception, led

i cannot find the null pointer exception in my code, i was wondering if anyone could help me find what is giving an error.
code:
        package com.dingle.ubat;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UltraBrightAndroidTorchActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 PowerManager pm;
 PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
 public boolean flash = false;
 public boolean enableFlash = false;
 public boolean dimDisplay = false;
 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
 public int windowWidth = display.getWidth();
 public int windowHeight = display.getHeight();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    flash = this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
    if(flash == true && enableFlash == true){
    try {
            DroidLED led = new DroidLED();
            led.enable(!led.isEnabled());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error interacting with LED.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }  }

    wl.acquire();

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //int tx = (int) event.getRawX();
    int ty = (int) event.getRawY();
    if (ty <= (windowHeight/2)){
        dimDisplay = !dimDisplay;
    }
    if (ty >= (windowHeight/2)){
        enableFlash = !enableFlash;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    wl.release();
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    wl.release();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    wl.release();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    wl.release();
}

}
```

Error list:

```
    12-10 20:40:42.224: W/dalvikvm(274): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
12-10 20:40:42.232: E/AndroidRuntime(274): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.dingle.ubat/com.dingle.ubat.UltraBrightAndroidTorchActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.dingle.ubat.UltraBrightAndroidTorchActivity.<init>(UltraBrightAndroidTorchActivity.java:20)
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1479)
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
12-10 20:40:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  ... 11 more
```

any help and criticism is greatly appreciated
code is being compiled for android 2.1. code is a basic, crappily coded torch app.
thanx

Comment: why not set a breakpoint in your onCreate method to debug which line of code failed to instantiate

Comment: @Chunhui: the NPE is raised in `<init>`, `onCreate` hasn't had a chance to be called yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is bailing out on one of these two lines:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
public int windowWidth = display.getWidth();
```

Either `getWindowManager()` is returning a `null` and that first initializer will fail, or `getDefaultDisplay()` is, and the second one will.

You should probably move these initializations to the `onCreate` handler. Having them at instance  initialization sounds a bit risky - the activity's "environment" might not be completely set up yet at that point.

(And check the return values.)

Answer (score 0):

Activity is full available only after it has been created. This line does not do the intended purpose:

```
 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
```

Move this line and subsequent ones inside `onCreate` method.